# web push notification in android native application

Tags: java, android, webview, push-notification, web-push

Is there any way to show a website push notification in android native application(or web-view)?

*Note* that I don't have admin access to that website and I only want to show that website notifications in my android app.

Answer (score 0):

As of June 2017, as you can see on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Push_API) ("Browser Support"), the Android WebView doesn't support web push.